# How to obtain request headers, remote address and other HttpServletRequest-specific information?

Tags: servlets, jsf-2

I have a  JSF 2.0 web project, my web have a form and it have to do:

1. Get the parametres of the form and save it in a Bean (Done)
2. Get this information from the servlet:

   - Remote Address:
   - Remote Host:
   - Locale:
   - Content Type:
   - Boundary:
   - Content Length:
   - Character Encoding:
3. Insert the Bean data and Servlet data in a table of a database (waiting step 2)

I dont know much about Servlets in JSF, i dont need if i have to make one or not. I only have the code of that but in JSP:

```
    String informe="";
    Enumeration a = request.getHeaderNames();
    while(a.hasMoreElements() ){
        String h = a.nextElement().toString();
        informe += h+": "+request.getHeader(h)+"\n";
    }
    a = request.getAttributeNames();
    while(a.hasMoreElements() ){
        String h = a.nextElement().toString();
        informe += h+": "+request.getHeader(h)+"\n";
    }
    informe += "Remote Address: "+request.getRemoteAddr()+"\n";
    informe += "Remote Host: "+request.getRemoteHost()+"\n";
    informe += "Locale: "+request.getLocale()+"\n";
    informe += "Content Type: "+request.getContentType()+"\n";
    informe += "Content Length: "+request.getContentLength()+"\n";
            .....
            ..
```

I don't know how I can get the request information in JSF and wich steps I have to do. I readed a lot of pages but I think that I don't need all things that they do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `HttpServletRequest` object is in JSF available by [`ExternalContext#getRequest()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequest%28%29).

```
ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) externalContext.getRequest();
// ...
```

The [`ExternalContext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html) by the way also offers some direct methods to get the desired information. Check the methods starting with `getRequestXxx()` such as `getRequestHeaderMap()`, `getRequestContentType()`, etc in the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html).

You don't need another servlet for this. JSF has already the `FacesServlet` as the sole request/response controller.

Comment: You are my saver!! XDD Give me 4 of reputation and i will vote your post XDD  thanks man