# How can I get the remote windows login from a JSF?

Tags: spring, jsf-2, spring-security

I want to retrieve the Windows login of my users when they run my JSF script. The goal is to avoid asking my user a login information, just want get the Windows login throw the request.

I try  this [How to obtain request headers, remote address and other HttpServletRequest-specific information?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8579321/how-to-obtain-request-headers-remote-address-and-other-httpservletrequest-speci) but I always get a null String with externalContext.getRemoteUser().

Does it mean that the web browser doesn't send the remote user information? Must I change the configuration of my browser? Is it possible to get this information?

Thanks,

Philippe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Spring security kerberos plugin](http://blog.springsource.com/2009/09/28/spring-security-kerberos/) will pull this off quite nicely, but you'll be taking the spring framework on as a dependency. I'm also assuming here that you're running a managed security enterprise where your users authenticate against a domain.

What you want to achieve cannot be done by pure Java EE spec (someone prove otherwise). The purpose of the `getRemoteUser` method is to retrieve the username of the authenticated user who has been authenticated either by the Webapp container or third party web auth framework. See spec [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.3/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser())

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9778242/1530938) for more insight